# Solr: Opening hours, whats open now

Tags: datetime, search, solr

I have looked around everywhere, but could not find a single place which actually gives an answer, there are many places where ideas are shared but no actual end to end example/solution is given.

What i need is very simple, i have a bunch of restaurants that have opening hours
Each restaurant could have different opening hours in a day (i.e open from 9-11, then from 13-15 and maybe then 18-21) 
Each place could have different schedule per days of the week, lets say on weekends and Wednesdays they do half a day.

My data in db is stored like below:

```
|Restaurant ID| Day of week | Open time  |Close time|
|Pizza123     | 1           | 0800       | 1100     |
|Pizza123     | 1           | 1300       | 1500     |
|Pizza123     | 1           | 1700       | 2100     |
|Pizza123     | 2           | 0800       | 1500     |
|Pizza123     | 2           | 1800       | +0200    |
.......
```

From what i read i need to consider Solrs [SpatialForTimeDurations](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialForTimeDurations), which explains to me the following:

1. I would store my opening time as X
2. I would store my closing time as Y
3. Which is then expressed as X Y (x space y)
4. I would supply these values as a String to Solr
5. These values should be supplied to a field of type solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType

This is as far as i have gotten.

Below are my questions:

What about the day of the week? this only solves the problem for opening/closing hours

How would i query for any place thats open "now"?

How would i query for any place that will be open for the next hour or tomorrow noon?

How would i deal with opening hours that span across two days, see last example in the sample DB table above.

Please share sample queries so i can wrap my head around it

Please let me know is there anything else that i am missing

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have managed to resolve this, for anyone interested the answer can be found here http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DateRangeField